Flipping text in Excel file
I have a spreadsheet (900 cells wide and 2000 long) with a design that I need to flip both vertically and horizontally.
I manually converted the text in about 30 text boxes and then applied 3D rotation flipping in the Y axis only.
In Excel if I flip in both the X and Y axis it doesn't work.  But when I print to pdf and then horizontally reverse it again via the pdf printer it comes out perfect.
I now have about 1000 cells (not text boxes) with text.
I'm looking to highlight a cell and run a macro that cuts the cell text, pastes it into a text box in that cell, and then flips the 3D rotation by 180 degrees.
The cells with text in them are all different sizes, and I have no idea how to automate adding text boxes to fill each cell.
The result should look like this.

CODE - 20 AUG
Sub Loop_For_Rectangle_Checking_If_Populated_And_Merged()

    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2txt As Range
    
    For Each rng In Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B2:AET2000")
        
        'check cell is not empty
        If rng.Value <> "" Then
        
            'check cell is part of merged range
            If rng.MergeCells Then
                Set rng2txt = rng.MergeArea
            Else
                Set rng2txt = rng
            End If
    
            'create rectangle matching dimensions of range
            Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle( _
                Left:=rng2txt.Left, _
                Top:=rng2txt.Top, _
                Width:=rng2txt.Width, _
                Height:=rng2txt.Height)
            
            'clear contents of cell
            rng2txt.ClearContents
        
        End If
        
    Next rng
    
End Sub

CODE - 22 AUG
Sub Loop_Add_White_Rectangle_Checking_If_Populated_And_Merged()

    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2txt As Range
    
    For Each rng In Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B2:AET2000")
        
        'check cell is not empty
        If rng.Value <> "" Then
        
            'check cell is part of merged range
            If rng.MergeCells Then
                Set rng2txt = rng.MergeArea
            Else
                Set rng2txt = rng
            End If
    
            'add rectangle matching dimensions of range
            Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape( _
                Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
                Left:=rng2txt.Left, _
                Top:=rng2txt.Top, _
                Width:=rng2txt.Width, _
                Height:=rng2txt.Height)
            
            'white background with no lines
            shp.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbWhite
            shp.Line.Visible = msoFalse
            
            'clear contents of cell
            rng2txt.ClearContents
        
        End If
        
    Next rng
    
End Sub


You can create a text box and set its position and dimensions to match those of the selected cell using the code below.
I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do regarding flipping/rotating so the code below assumes you want to flip the text box vertically.
Sub Single_Text_Box()

    Dim shp As Shape
    
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=ActiveCell.Left, _
        Top:=ActiveCell.Top, _
        Width:=ActiveCell.Width, _
        Height:=ActiveCell.Height)
    
    shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = ActiveCell.Text
    shp.Flip msoFlipVertical
    
    ActiveCell.ClearContents
    
End Sub

If you do want to rotate the 3D Y axis 180 degrees you can replace the following line:
shp.Flip msoFlipVertical

With this one:
shp.ThreeD.RotationY = 180

I'm not sure if you really want to run this macro individually for each one of 1000 cells.  Instead, you could wrap the whole thing in a loop to process every cell in a specified range (I've limited it to A1:B5 in the example below):
Sub Loop_For_Text_Boxes()

    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim rng As Range
    
    For Each rng In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B5")
    
        Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
            Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
            Left:=rng.Left, _
            Top:=rng.Top, _
            Width:=rng.Width, _
            Height:=rng.Height)
        
        shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = rng.Text
        shp.Flip msoFlipVertical
    
        rng.ClearContents
        
    Next rng
    
End Sub

The above code will add a text box to every cell in the specified range.  If you want to check for cells containing something, you could do the following:
Sub Loop_For_Text_Boxes_Checking_If_Populated()

    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim rng As Range
    
    For Each rng In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B5")
        
        If rng.Value <> "" Then
    
            Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
                Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                Left:=rng.Left, _
                Top:=rng.Top, _
                Width:=rng.Width, _
                Height:=rng.Height)
            
            shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = rng.Text
            shp.Flip msoFlipVertical
            shp.Flip msoFlipHorizontal
        
            'rng.ClearContents
        
        End If
        
    Next rng
    
End Sub

If you need to deal with merged cells, you can test the MergeCells property and use the MergeArea property to return the range of merged cells:
Sub Loop_For_Text_Boxes_Checking_If_Populated_And_Merged()

    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2txt As Range
    
    For Each rng In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B5")
        
        'check cell is not empty
        If rng.Value <> "" Then
        
            'check cell is part of merged range
            If rng.MergeCells Then
                Set rng2txt = rng.MergeArea
            Else
                Set rng2txt = rng
            End If
    
            'create text box matching dimensions of range
            Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
                Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                Left:=rng2txt.Left, _
                Top:=rng2txt.Top, _
                Width:=rng2txt.Width, _
                Height:=rng2txt.Height)
            
            'add text and center horizontally and vertically
            With shp.TextFrame2
                .TextRange.Text = rng2txt.Cells(1, 1).Text
                .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
                .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
            End With
            
            'rotate 180 degrees on Y axis
            shp.ThreeD.RotationY = 180
            
            'clear contents of cell
            rng2txt.ClearContents
        
        End If
        
    Next rng
    
End Sub

Edit to include a background rectangle:
Sub Add_Rectangles_And_Text_Boxes()

    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rng2txt As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    
    Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet3")
    
    For Each rng In sh.Range("B2:AET2000")
        
        'check cell is not empty
        If rng.Value <> "" Then
        
            'check cell is part of merged range
            If rng.MergeCells Then
                Set rng2txt = rng.MergeArea
            Else
                Set rng2txt = rng
            End If
            
            'create rectangle matching dimensions of range
            Set shp = sh.Shapes.AddShape( _
                Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _
                Left:=rng2txt.Left, _
                Top:=rng2txt.Top, _
                Width:=rng2txt.Width, _
                Height:=rng2txt.Height)
                
            With shp
                'set fill colour
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = rgbWhite
                'remove border
                .Line.Visible = msoFalse
            End With
            
            'create text box matching dimensions of range
            Set shp = sh.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
                Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                Left:=rng2txt.Left, _
                Top:=rng2txt.Top, _
                Width:=rng2txt.Width, _
                Height:=rng2txt.Height)
            
            'add text and center horizontally and vertically
            With shp.TextFrame2
                .TextRange.Text = rng2txt.Cells(1, 1).Text
                .TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = msoAlignCenter
                .VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
            End With
            
            With shp
                'rotate 180 degrees on Y axis
                .ThreeD.RotationY = 180
                'remove fill colour
                .Fill.Visible = msoFalse
            End With
            
            'clear contents of cell
            rng2txt.ClearContents
        
        End If
        
    Next rng
    
End Sub


Thanks very much, a quick google that looks to do what I'm after and yes I do want to rotate Y 180 degrees - beginner though how exactly can I run this, assume it's VBA.?   Also will that automatically find and change text in cells to text boxes in the chosen range.?

Hi David, sorry yes, you said you wanted to run a macro to do this so I assumed you knew VBA.  To make it work: 1) Open the Visual Basic Editor (choose Developer | Visual Basic in the Excel ribbon or press Alt + F11). 2) From the VB Editor menu choose Insert | Module. 3) Paste the code into the module. You can run it in several ways. In Excel you can choose Developer | Macros from the ribbon then double-click the macro you want to run.  If you want to run the Single_Text_Box macro, make sure you select the cell you want to convert into a text box first.

The current code in Loop_For_Text_Boxes will add a text box to every cell in the specified range.  I'll edit the answer to include a check for non-empty cells.

ha it's been probably 10yrs since I did a lot with macros it's funny how quickly you forget.  Thanks.!!!  The code was brilliant - almost, but my bad.!   I actually didn't realise, but probably should have, that all the text is both in merged cells and is also centred horizontally and vertically, so it worked as planned however only for the first cell of the merge.  However is there any way to run the macro across merged cells.?  Once it's there even if backwards I'm assuming I can change font and color etc easy enough.

Okay, I've edited to include a version which checks for merged cells. And yes, you can format the text in each text box normally afterwards.

Thanks Andrew so much, that worked a treat  :) :)     Though I've now found a bug in Excel where is you reverse the text box as I've done and it's a plain white full color background there is no way to make it plain white, it goes grey and mid grey at that.  Every other color works fine apart from white - very odd.  But the adding text box to fill the exact cell size was the kicker, thanks so much it has saved me weeks of work!!

Happy to hear that it helped!

Just following on I escalated with our MS contact who just reverted indeed it has been flagged as a bug, however the workaround is to add a Rectangle shape with a white Background Color behind the TextBox, and change the TextBox Background Color to none, this works.  I can do the bring front send back layering of them manually but as last time adding the boxes, merged boxes and dimensions is by far the most time consuming.  I've done my (noob :( :(   ) best to adapt your prior code for this but it is not working, see above.  I'm sure it's close any assistance would be appreciated.

Do the cells already have a white background colour?  You could just set each of the text boxes to No FIll like so:
shp.Fill.Visible = msoFalse

I'd do this after the line which sets the 3D Y rotation to 180.

Thanks Andrew, I've manually done that for cells over white background, about 25%, and that works fine.  The rest are complex sizes and have multiple color objects behind them, and in some cases stacked layering, I was hoping to exactly replicate the text box objects on the top layer with a white fill rectangle behind (or even in front) of them and then I can manually play with the layers to get it right, have tested with basic shapes behind a couple and that seems to get the best results.  I felt I was close with your code but couldn't quite nail it . . .

OK you can add a basic rectangle in almost the same way as a text box but instead of the AddTextbox method use the AddShape method Set shp =  ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape The AddShape method doesn't have an Orientation parameter (so don't put Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal) but it does have a Type parameter so you'll need to include Type:=msoShapeRectangle. Set the Left, Top, Width and Height in the same way as the text box. After this you can set the fill colour with shp.Fill.Forecolor.RGB = rgbWhite and maybe switch off the border with shp.Line.Visible = msoFalse Hope it helps!

Thanks again @Andrew Gould, please see my code above - I've added everything apart from the period (.) at the end of the Type:=msoShapeRectangle. which didn't seem to work, so I changed it to Type:=msoShapeRectangle, _ which I'm hoping is right, but it wouldn't add a rectangle.  Spent about an hour trying to debug and while it's running without error, I can't get it worked out, sorry.

Hi David, did you run your code separately after already running the code to add the text boxes? If so, the If statement which checks for non-empty cells won't work because the cells will have been cleared. I've added an edited version to add the rectangles and text boxes in the same procedure.

Sorry to report @Andrew Gould that on running the code from the original file it does indeed change the existing text to text boxes and adds a white rectangle behind them - both of these are perfect, however the one I'm having all the difficulty with is the original (complex) text boxes, and it unfortunately it doesn't rotate them 180 degrees, remove the fill colour or create a white rectangle behind these. I have then tried running the original 'text boxes' code but as you say it doesn't work after already running the other one.

Hi David, yeah that code won't do anything to any existing text boxes.
